# Removing a cached response from ResponseCache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, model-view-controller

My page doesn't change a lot (a change in several days) but when they do, the change must reflect immediately. So for the first part (not changing a lot) it seems wise to use a long duration for `ResponseCache` but at the other hand as changes must be reflected immediately, forces even not using the caching.

Is there anyway to remove cached response whenever I want to?

Comment: do you want to remove cache response for specific controller action or remove it in ConfigureServices method according to condition?

Comment: @hsnbl No, actually i found what you said in questions. Imagine that **Index** action is cached, and now there is change in that page. i want to tell the cache to clear cache for **Index** action so that changes apply to output and new one gets cached. and I don't want to just disable caching for it

Comment: Can you try to use [ResponseCache(Location="Client")] onto your action

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.responsecacheattribute#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ResponseCacheAttribute_Location
Reference2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10565986/8175473

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force Cache Refresh When Editing and Redisplaying Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629299/force-cache-refresh-when-editing-and-redisplaying-content)